# angular 2+ listen component event when using routing <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Tags: angular, events, routes, components

I have 2 components

1. app-component (main component).
2. poductsList-component (List of Products).

app- component listen to editClick event(for instance) that rise from poductsList-component

when use click edit on a product(shown on poductsList-component) event is fire, and since app- component listen for this component I can run any code I want to.

every thing was good till I decide to use routing (update address par, allow back act..)
now the component inject to  with no ability to add event listener...

so I can't get any notification that user click on edit product for instance...what can I do in order to allow app-component listen to event on child component  (poductsList-component)

any idea? (what did I miss)

Comment: I didn't understand your problem but you can subscribe router events.